# Trouble visualizing voltage-shunt mixing

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback

I'm trying to understand how voltage-shunt feedback works in an inverting op-amp circuit.  I can't seem to visualize how the feedback gets mixed in shunt with the input.

NB: Before I tried this, I was able to understand voltage-series feedback in a similar non-inverting op-amp circuit.  I redrew the circuit until I could "see" that the feedback network was in parallel with the output voltage and in series with the input voltage.  Here is the circuit I'm working on now.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpdGjy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I redrew it (below) to help me visualize that the feedback network is in shunt, and I am suitably convinced that the feedback network is actually sampling the voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5efhA.png)</sup>

But I can't for the life of me visualize how the feedback is applying itself in shunt on the input side.  R1 sure looks like it's sitting in series with the input to me, but I know that's not correct.  Somehow, it's in shunt and capable of applying a current in a manner different from how the voltage-series feedback worked.  **Can anyone redraw what I have to help me see it?**

EDIT - Put another way, I'm trying to reconcile the differences above with block diagrams I see like this (below), which clearly show the feedback being applied in shunt.  [source](https://www.ques10.com/p/22200/explain-feedback-topologies-with-the-help-of-nea-1/)
[image]

Comment: Your two op-amps circuits are identical.

Comment: Andy, yes they are identical.  I am looking for help in seeing how the circuit could possibly be voltage-shunt when the mixing appears to be in series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualise In- as a virtual earth.

All currents into that node will sum to 0 (the input current of the opamp, which is infinite impedance) and the voltage at the node will also be 0 (because In+ is hardwired to 0, and open loop gain is infinite)

These two constraints define its operation (within its linear range).

Therefore mixing occurs through the summation of all input currents plus the output current, whose result is 0.

Therefore the output voltage is whatever is required to oppose the linear sum of the input currents through Rf.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEG1Ti.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

"Shunt" effectively means "connected in parallel" and hopefully you can see that the feedback path (to virtual ground) is in parallel with the load (to actual ground).

I hope you can see this circuit is both identical to yours, and identical in topology with ONLY your "Voltage Shunt" diagram.

Answer (score 1):

To analyze this circuit in terms of the formalism of the four feedback topologies, it is helpful to associate R1 with the source network, not the feedback network. It then becomes easy to see that the source network and feedback network (Rf) combine in parallel on the input side.

You can proceed with the rest of the four-feedback-topology analysis by redrawing the source network, which now consists of your voltage source and R1,  as a Thevenin equivalent current source in parallel with a source resistor.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> R1 sure looks like it's sitting in series with the input to me, but I know that's not correct.

Why do you think that?  Your first schematic shows R1 in series with the input voltage source, which is correct.

Another way to think of it is that the input signal is a current source rather than a voltage source, in parallel with R1.  In that case, R1 is a shunt resistor.

Comment: My understanding was - and this may be incorrect! - that this circuit was using voltage sampling and current mixing (voltage-shunt).  Is it?